# How to check and control for autocorrelation in a mixed effect model of longitudinal data?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-models, temporal, longitudinal

I have behavioral data for many groups of birds over 10 days of observation. I wanted to investigate whether there is a temporal pattern in some behaviors (e.g. does mate competition increase over time?) And I was told that I had to account for the autocorrelation of the data, since behavior is unlikely to be independent in each day.

However I was wondering about two things:

1. Since I'm not interested in the differences in y among days but the trend of y over days, do I still need to correct for autocorrelation?
2. If yes, how do I control for the autocorrelation so that I'm left out only with the signal (and noise of course)?

For the second question, keep in mind I will be analyzing the effect of time on behavior using mixed models in R (since there are random effects such as pseudo-replication), but I have not found any straightforward method of correcting for autocorrelation in the data when modeling the responses.

Answer (score 7):

(1) Yes, you should check for/account for autocorrelation.

The first example [here](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/ecostats_chap.html) shows an example of estimating trends in a mixed model while accounting for autocorrelation.

You can fit these models with `lme` from the `nlme` package.  Here's a mixed model *without* autocorrelation included:

```
cmod_lme <- lme(GS.NEE ~ cYear,
            data=mc2, method="REML",
            random = ~ 1 + cYear | Site)
```

and you can explore the autocorrelation by using `plot(ACF(cmod_lme))`.

(2) Add correlation to the model something like this:

```
cmod_lme_acor <- update(cmod_lme, 
       correlation=corAR1(form=~cYear|Site)
```

@JeffreyGirard notes that

> to check the ACF after updating the model to include the correlation argument, you will need to use `plot(ACF(cmod_lme_acor, resType = "normalized"))`

Comment: Hi, in your example it looked like you are looking at autocorrelation on the random effects. Can I use it in the fixed effects? In my case the independent variable is time (days), but time itself can cause the autocorrelation I'm trying to correct. So do I have to have time as both fixed and random effects? My model be something like this:

(g)lmer(Behavior ~ Time + (1|groupID), data = bird)

Comment: This models autocorrelation in the residuals. `~cYear|Site` means that `cYear` is the time-ordering variable and `Site` is the grouping variable (i.e., residuals are only correlated within groups); you would want something like `correlation=corAR1(formula=~Time|groupID)`. This is for `lme`; you can't easily do it with GLMMs.

Comment: Tried to add the correlation structre with correlation=corAR1(formula = ~time|Site) but it gives me an error. Turns out that the code now is correlation=corAR1(form = ~time|Site)

Comment: Note that to check the ACF after updating the model to include the correlation argument, you will need to use `plot(ACF(cmod_lme_acor, resType = "normalized"))` or it will show you a version that was not corrected.