# R: Mixed effects model with autocorrelated errors in nlme Package: How do I check model the ARMA assumptions?

Tags: r, statistics, mixed-models, nlme

I am setting up a LME model with the following structure in R, using the package nlme:

```
model <- lme(y ~ x, random = ~ 1 | group, data = data, correlation = corARMA(form = ~ x | group, p=1, q=1)
```

Comparing AIC values, this model seems to compare better to a model without autocorrelated residuals. But how do I check my model assumptions regarding the ARMA model? Most importantly, how do I check whether the residuals of ARMA model are not correlated anymore?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check out if there is auto-correlation in standardized/normalized residuals.

```
acf(residuals(model, type = "normalized"))
```

Ideally it should look like white noise.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is an underappreciated point (it's mentioned in passing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796175/how-to-check-and-control-for-autocorrelation-in-a-mixed-effect-model-of-longitud)  and [here](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/misc/foxchapter/bolker_chap.html) (search for "normalized"). The answer would be improved, I think, with a quote from `?nlme::residuals.lme` explaining what this option means ...